# Send private message to Discord user using bash and linux AT command

Tags: python, bash, shell, discord, bots

I'm running a Discord bot written in Python `nohup python3 ./bot.py &`. With this bot you can schedule a task which has to run only once. I'm executing bash from Python to schedule a script to run at a certain time. This works.

I want to send the user a private message in Discord that the command has been executed. I can't think a way how to send the user a private message after the bash command has been executed. I know the username of the user because its part of the scheduled job.

My question: what is the best way to send a user a message using bash? If possible..

Comment: Can you explain more,
What im understanding is that your want to send a message to a user using discord.py and want to able to run this script with bash?
So do you need help with how to message someone with discord py?
Im sorry if im asking a stupid question

Comment: in short: I want to send the user a private message via bash

Comment: So you want the bot to turn, on send a message to a specific person, and then turn off, all in one bash script.

Do you want to specify the user everytime or will it be hard coded in the script.

Answer (score 0):

The code will be:

```
import sys

@client.event()
async def on_ready()
    user = int(sys.argv[1])
    user = await client.fetch_user(user)

    message = str(sys.argv[2])
    await user.send(message)
```

Now you can go `python3 bot.py <userid> “<message>“`
The message must be in “” the user id must be the user id and not the name.
If you dont want to specify the user/message everytime,Just change the variable